# Rails rufus scheduler intercepted an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rufus-scheduler, tzinfo

I was basically fetching every country time through timezone and was storing in my constant.rb file .But it is throwing an error .I am using tzinfo gem for fetching the time .I don't know how to resolve this error

[my_task_scheduler.rb]

```
require 'rufus/scheduler'  
require "rubygems"
require "net/https"
require "uri"
require "json"
require 'tzinfo'


s = Rufus::Scheduler.new
s.every '1m' do 

    Tzone.each do |zone|    
        time = TZInfo::Timezone.get(zone)
         puts time.now.strftime("%I:%M %P")

    end 
end
```

[constant.rb]

```
Ctime = ["05:00"]

Tzone = [ "International Date Line West",
"Midway Island" ,
"American Samoa" ,
"Hawaii" ,
"Alaska" ,
"Pacific Time (US & Canada)" ,
"Tijuana" ]
```

my error is

```
{ 70091014224280 rufus-scheduler intercepted an error:
  70091014224280   job:
  70091014224280     Rufus::Scheduler::EveryJob "1m" {}
  70091014224280   error:
  70091014224280     70091014224280
  70091014224280     TZInfo::InvalidTimezoneIdentifier
  70091014224280     Invalid identifier
  70091014224280       /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/zoneinfo_data_source.rb:208:in `load_timezone_info'
  70091014224280       /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/timezone.rb:92:in `get'
  70091014224280       /home/techbirds/shivam/config/initializers/my_tasks_scheduler.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  70091014224280       /home/techbirds/shivam/config/initializers/my_tasks_scheduler.rb:13:in `each'
  70091014224280       /home/techbirds/shivam/config/initializers/my_tasks_scheduler.rb:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
  70091014224280       /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.1.10/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:234:in `call'
  70091014224280       /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.1.10/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:234:in `do_call'
  70091014224280       /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.1.10/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:258:in `do_trigger'
  70091014224280       /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.1.10/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:300:in `block (3 levels) in start_work_thread'
  70091014224280       /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.1.10/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:303:in `call'
  70091014224280       /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.1.10/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:303:in `block (2 levels) in start_work_thread'
  70091014224280       /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.1.10/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:289:in `loop'
  70091014224280       /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.1.10/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:289:in `block in start_work_thread'
  70091014224280   tz:
  70091014224280     ENV['TZ']: 
  70091014224280     Time.now: 2016-01-06 10:29:47 +0530
  70091014224280   scheduler:
  70091014224280     object_id: 46315140
  70091014224280     opts:
  70091014224280       {}
  70091014224280       frequency: 0.3
  70091014224280       scheduler_lock: #<Rufus::Scheduler::NullLock:0x00000004872158>
  70091014224280       trigger_lock: #<Rufus::Scheduler::NullLock:0x00000004872108>
  70091014224280     uptime: 60.072723042 (1m72)
  70091014224280     down?: false
  70091014224280     threads: 2
  70091014224280       thread: #<Thread:0x00000004872090>
  70091014224280       thread_key: rufus_scheduler_46315140
  70091014224280       work_threads: 1
  70091014224280         active: 1
  70091014224280         vacant: 0
  70091014224280         max_work_threads: 28
  70091014224280       mutexes: {}
  70091014224280     jobs: 1
  70091014224280       at_jobs: 0
  70091014224280       in_jobs: 0
  70091014224280       every_jobs: 1
  70091014224280       interval_jobs: 0
  70091014224280       cron_jobs: 0
  70091014224280     running_jobs: 1
  70091014224280     work_queue: 0
} 70091014224280 .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use time zone identifiers for [`ActiveSupport::TimeZone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) with TZInfo. However, TZInfo only understands identifiers from the [IANA Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). The 'invalid identifier' error you are seeing indicates that it has been passed something that it doesn't recognize.

Behind the scenes, `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` uses TZInfo to perform conversions. You can see the mapping from the `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` identifiers to IANA Time Zone Database identifiers in `ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING`.

You could switch to using the equivalent IANA Time Zone Database identifiers from the mapping:

```
require 'tzinfo'

Tzone = [
  "Pacific/Midway",      # International Date Line West
  "Pacific/Midway",      # Midway Island
  "Pacific/Pago_Pago",   # American Samoa
  "Pacific/Honolulu",    # Hawaii
  "America/Juneau",      # Alaska
  "America/Los_Angeles", # Pacific Time (US & Canada)
  "America/Tijuana"]     # Tijuana

Tzone.each do |zone|
  time = TZInfo::Timezone.get(zone)
  puts time.now.strftime("%I:%M %P")
end
```

You could also keep using your existing time zone identifiers and use `ActiveSupport` to perform your calculations instead:

```
require 'active_support/all'

Tzone = [
  "International Date Line West",
  "Midway Island",
  "American Samoa",
  "Hawaii",
  "Alaska",
  "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
  "Tijuana"]

Tzone.each do |zone|
  Time.use_zone(zone) do
    puts Time.zone.now.strftime("%I:%M %P")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your error is an "Invalid identifier", I ran this simplified version of your code to determine which identifier is invalid:

```
require 'tzinfo'

zones = [
  "International Date Line West",
  "Midway Island" ,
  "American Samoa" ,
  "Hawaii" ,
  "Alaska" ,
  "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" ,
  "Tijuana" ]

zones.each do |zone|
  p zone
  p TZInfo::Timezone.get(zone)
end
```

And it says "Invalid identifier" for "International Date Line West".

As a programmer, you have to learn to read error messages.

The solution would be to use a time zone name known by the tzinfo gem.

**UPDATE**

```
require 'tzinfo'

p TZInfo::Timezone.get("International Date Line West")
```

results in

```
~/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/zoneinfo_data_source.rb:208:
  in `load_timezone_info': Invalid identifier (TZInfo::InvalidTimezoneIdentifier)
  from ~/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/timezone.rb:92:
  in `get'
  from t3.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

What is happening is simply that the "tzinfo" gem does not know any time zone named "International Date Line West", and it raises the error you see when you try to get it.

**UPDATE**

This seems to work:

```
require 'tzinfo'

p TZInfo::Timezone.get("Etc/GMT+12")
```

Hope it helps.

IIRC, this is a list of zones that tzinfo should understand: https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/blob/be17a0bda680d06e5f435de3c644fee17c403965/lib/rufus/scheduler/zones.rb#L28

Comment: Sorry i am not able to understand what you are trying to say can you please elaborate

Comment: OH that i understand but for eg this is the timezone "International Date Line West" => "Pacific/Midway"  i need to fetch from this part "International Date Line West only not from this  part Pacific/Midway Do u have any idea sir how can i do that?

Comment: Updated, "Etc/GMT+12" should be OK.

Comment: If you read carefully ALL of my answer, you will understand what I mean by "Etc/GMT+12".

Comment: I understand what you are trying to mean but i need International Date Line West only and you are saying tzinfo doesn;t accept this ..so any idea how to do that any other gem or soemthing else

Comment: I cannot give Etc/GMT+12 this as an argument

Comment: The international date line is not a time zone. West of the international date line is the time zone named "Etc/GMT+12". Got it?

Comment: "Etc/GMT+12", a String, surrounded by double quotes!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99881/discussion-between-jmettraux-and-user5729333).

Comment: check that link i want the key part of every timezone ..i know i can use etc/GMT+12 but i have to provide the key part of every timezone of the link which i have provided